# why SciTE's output is reversed?

Tags: lua, scite

I'm writing my lua code with SciTE, 
i wrote a **C function** that could be invoked by lua like this:

```
int hello(lua_State* L){
printf("----->> Hi! %s\n", lua_tostring(L, 1));
return 0;
}
```

and my **lua code** is like this:

```
zcLua.hello('Kitty')
print'hello'
```

('zcLua' is the libname i registered). in lua console, the output is

```
----->> Hi! Kitty
hello
```

but in SciTE the output is reversed :

```
hello
----->> Hi! Kitty
```

how can i correct that? seems it's because code `print'hello'` is executed faster than invoking the c function

Comment: How does `printf` work? That's not a standard Lua function.

Comment: no it's not a lua function. it's c/c++ code. i'm testing to bind lua to c

Comment: As I don't know SciTE, I can't tell it for sure. But I think the `print` function is refined in the editor, which places the output data in a _buffer_ that is only displayed at the end of script, or in a separate thread.

Comment: prapin explanation make sense. odd behaviour though. i would'n care too much about the "late" output from your C-binding. it seems to work and i guess you have all set up properly. The execution order will be preserved. you could print a value passed in through the stack (lua_State) to prove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I don't know SciTE, I can't tell it for sure. But I think the print function is refined in the editor, which places the output data in a buffer that is only displayed at the end of script, or in a separate thread.